# How to (roughly) calculate torque for cordless drill clutch settings?

Tags: drill

Is it possible to (roughly) calculate the torque limits that correspond to the clutch settings on my cordless drill? I use my drill to do quick on/off attachments of a kid trailer (and other things) on my bicycle. I'd like to be able to set my clutch rather than the guessing I do today. The only way I can think of to do it is to tighten a bolt in a piece of scrap metal/wood using a calibrated torque wrench and then working my way up the clutch settings to find the closest setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes as you stated You could buy a torque wrench clamp it to a work bench or put it in vise and then go through all of the settings on you drill to get an idea of the torque each setting provides,

but then you have the **CORRECT** TOOL FOR THE JOB and would no longer need the incorrect tool ( drill/driver ) for the tasks you are performing.

Comment: I just want to be able to quickly take something on/off my bike and know that I'm using a sufficient torque without exceeding/approaching the maximum. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use the clutch setting every day, and I find the final torque is affected by speed, momentum, and use after adjustment. If I increase the setting and use it, the torque result is higher for the first go. Then it reduces a bit for subsequent uses. It is not an accurate mechanism, just a back spring pressing against a toothed pawl.
It helps to watch the nut/bolt turning as it reaches final torque, to get a feel for the torque.